# python 3.2 error saying urllib.parse.urlencode() is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.2

I am trying to use urllib.parse.urlencode() method in one of my scripts. 
import urllib

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.2

import urllib

data = urllib.parse.urlencode({'type': 'device_code','client_id': 150792241632891})
```

It was working before but now I get following error.

**Output**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rakesh/programming/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode({'type': 'device_code','client_id': 150792241632891})
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'parse'
```

Initially I doubt my python shell but when I checked it is using python version 3.2 which should be fiine.

Now I am totally perplexed why python shell is behaving this way.
Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Comment: @larsmans thanks for responding.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You're not showing the imports in your program, so I can't be sure, but I bet you did

```
import urllib
```

which will not import and re-export the separate module `urllib.parse`. Do

```
import urllib.parse
```

instead.

(`import urllib` is rather senseless in Python 3.x, since all the functionality is in the submodules and these are not imported by the toplevel module.)

Comment: thanks for responding.
Sorry I had missed the import statement while copying the code. Now I have edited my question.
   you solution worked for me. I guess accidently, I removed _.parse_ part from my import statement assuming that it will include submodule. Since earlier I had import urllib.parse thats why it was working before, but when I remove the submodule it didn't work and I was confuse.